# Translucency for leaves with the Principled BSDF

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I was wondering, what is the correct way to set up a leaf shader using the principled shader and translucency?

- Using the sss part of the principled shader gave weird results with one-sided meshes, as the backside was actually darker than the front part.
- I normally just added the translucency shader to the principled, but that caused some bugs when there were many bounces between close objects, which then added itself onto another and the energy exploded (white plant).
- Mixing Principled with translucency also gave weird results, as it automatically darkened the side of the leaf that was lit, if the translucent effect was strong (otherwise the translucency was simply too weak). I only used a value for the factor here, maybe there's a simple solution for what to use as a factor, but I don't know it.
- I also read that some people suggested using the transmission value, but this seems odd as it is for transmission and not translucency and also produced weird results.

Anyway, help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!